# Convert the value of a column to uppercase in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I need to convert the value of a column to uppercase in pig.

Was able to do using `UPPER` but this creates a new column.

For example:

```
A = Load 'MyFile.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (column1:chararray, column2:chararray, column3:chararray);
Dump A;
```

Returns

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

Now I need to convert second column to upper case.

```
B = Foreach A  generate *,UPPER(column2);
Dump B;
```

returns

```
a,b,c,B
e,f,g,F
```

But I need

```
a,B,c
e,F,g
```

Please let me know if there is a way to so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tried from my side but you can try like this

```
B = Foreach A  generate column1,UPPER(column2),column3;
```

Comment: This will work but my column structure will be dynamic and passed as parameter . I need to update the values according to the business logic.

Comment: Your question is generic. Update your question properly with inputs and what could be done based on input. What you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with user define function that default provided by Apache pig

**find PiggyBank Jar**

**command**

find / -name "piggybank*.jar*"

now goto pig  grunt shell

**code**

grunt> register /usr/local/pig-0.16.0/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;

grunt> A = Load 'data/MyFile.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (column1:chararray, column2:chararray, column3:chararray);

grunt> dump A;

**result**

(a,b,c)

(d,e,f)

**Now  convert second column to upper case.**

grunt> B =  foreach A generate column1,org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.UPPER(column2),column3;

grunt> dump B;

**result**

(a,B,c)

(d,E,f)

Answer (score 0):

Using the "*" in the below line is the reason for the extra column:

```
B = FOREACH A  generate *, UPPER(column2);
```

Instead use the below:

```
B = Foreach A  generate column1, UPPER(column2), column3;
```